# Generated Previews - low-resolution and dark shading fix?

Tags: blend-files

(2.79 - Blender Internal)

Generated Previews is very handy feature for previewing assets when importing / linking, I would just like to know if there is a way to:

1. Make thumbnails lighter to match the actual model shading (uses Shadeless materials)
2. Increase thumbnails resolution (or let a user to choose from variety of resolution presets) to get more clear preview when using large thumbnail view in the explorer

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you say "Make thumbnails lighter to match the actual model shading (uses Shadeless materials)" do you mean you have set the viewport to use material view? This only affects what you see in the viewport.
You could try adding more/stronger lights to the scene to make it brighter (check in fully shaded viewport)

Comment: @Steve I cannot check it right now, but I believe the previews are rendered using some custom lighting, so you can't adjust it by any scene lights.

Comment: Did you ask devs already? Even simple cube is dark.

Comment: @vklidu Unfortunately I think we shouldn't expect a fix because 2.79 is no more receiving any updates as I understand and 2.8x will get an asset manager to handle these things

Comment: 2.79b scene with Cube is bright.Test with 2.82 is dark ... and to be honest, I'm sure you know for how a long time the Asset Manager is on the TODO list.

Comment: Hmm, I used the 2.79 latest nightly build when making the screenshots. Yes, I know Asset Manager it will take some time, I just think we will have to live with that because it seems they will no more do any updates for 2.79 :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Q is related to old version of blender that is not going to be updated.

Comment: @vklidu That is not a valid reason to close the question. People are welcome to ask about any version of Blender.

Comment: @RayMairlot if there is a chance to help, sure, but OP is asking improve code that is abandoned, so there is no chance solve his Q, right? Or do you thing some one can change this hardcoded appearance of thumbnails? Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: @vklidu Source code questions are on topic, so if the answer requires a source code change (the user isn't *specifically* asking a source code question, it just may be the answer requires it) then that is fine. No reason someone familiar with the code couldn't look at the 2.79 code and provide a patch. Certainly unlikely, but it's still answerable. At the bare minimum the answer would be "This isn't possible without changing the source code and building blender."

Comment: isn't this thumbnail generated from your default camera? which is probably drawing like an HD 16:9 graphic, and that is probably then being scaled down with some poor interpolation to wind up with this crunchy mess. I would try adjusting the camera as if I was trying to draw a thumbnail and check if this has a bearing on the thumbnail generation. maybe we could ask for a feature to opt in to drawing thumbnails with viewport renderer, though blender historically was ray traced drawing. it makes sense "rendered" is what many artists expect to target in their files and be the default thumbnailer